# total point and store to session?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

```
<html>

<head>

</head> 

<form method="post" action="data.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td>question1</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
<td><input type="radio" name="D[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>            
</tr>
<tr>
<td>question2</td>
<td><input type="radio" name="I1" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="I[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>question3</td>
    <td><input type="radio" name="H1" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="H[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
                <td><label> question4 </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A[1]" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A[1]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A[1]" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A[1]" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A[1]" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A[1]" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A[1]" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A[1]" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A[1]" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="A[1]" value="10"> 10 </td>
        </tr><!-- 14 -->
            <tr>
                <td><label> question5 </label></td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D[2]" value="1"> 1 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D[2]" value="2"> 2 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D[2]" value="3"> 3 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D[2]" value="4"> 4 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D[2]" value="5"> 5 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D[2]" value="6"> 6 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D[2]" value="7"> 7 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D[2]" value="8"> 8 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D[2]" value="9"> 9 </td>
                <td><input type="radio" name="D[2]" value="10"> 10 </td>
            </tr><!-- 15 -->
            <tr>
<tr>
<td colspan=2>
<div align="center"><input type="button" name="submit" value="Score my test" onclick="javascript:tally()"></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</html>
```

my intetion is when the user checked the value from radio and store the value ,started with all name="D" (D1,D2,D3-D25) how to i make so many D value plus up and store with session ??

i am making a quiz webpage and user checked the value ( like D1 = 5 , D2= 10) how i plus those and store it into session ? i have being using java for loop but i cant pass those var to php. thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do a simple `+=` assignment operator. I made it a function, but it can be done in your loop.

**EDIT with the addition to echoing to the form**
I am presuming that this page is loading itself, otherwise the php stuff
goes into the `data.php` page.

```
<?php
session_start();

    function Plusifier($value = 0,$plus = 0)
        {
            // This is what does the adding...
            $value  +=  $plus;
            return $value;
        }

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            // Loop through POST arrays
            foreach($_POST as $letter => $vals) {
                    // If not the submit button
                    if(is_array($vals)) {
                            // Loop through POST arrays
                            foreach($vals as $sub => $values)
                                // Assign sessions
                                $_SESSION[$letter][$sub]    =   Plusifier($values,(isset($_SESSION[$letter][$sub]))? $_SESSION[$letter][$sub]:0);
                        }
                }
        }
?><html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="data.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>question1</td>
            <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { ?>
            <td><input type="radio" name="D[1]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
            <td colspan="2">TOTAL: <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['D'][1]))? $_SESSION['D'][1]: 0; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>question2</td>
            <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { ?>
            <td><input type="radio" name="I[1]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
            <td colspan="2">TOTAL: <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['I'][1]))? $_SESSION['I'][1]: 0; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>question3</td>
            <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { ?>
            <td><input type="radio" name="H[1]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
            <td colspan="2">TOTAL: <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['H'][1]))? $_SESSION['H'][1]: 0; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label> question4 </label></td>
            <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { ?>
            <td><input type="radio" name="A[1]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
            <td colspan="2">TOTAL: <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['A'][1]))? $_SESSION['A'][1]: 0; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 14 -->
        <tr>
            <td><label> question5 </label></td>
            <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { ?>
            <td><input type="radio" name="D[2]" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
            <td colspan="2">TOTAL: <?php echo (isset($_SESSION['D'][2]))? $_SESSION['D'][2]: 0; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 15 -->
        <tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=2><div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Score my test" ></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: how i going to add to the html ? so i make the name Plusifier($value,$plus);

Comment: You want to echo out the session to the inputs on the form too? Or rather you want to know how to get the stored values as well?

Comment: I will have to revise to show the whole code then. I thought you needed just the adding and setting session code.

Comment: I get the idea Rascalltt thank you but seem like the loop for radio didt work how i going to fix that ? i need the 1-10point radio. thank you give me a big help on this.

Comment: what's it doing or not doing?

Comment: the 1-10 html radio didt came out once test on browers , it was showing only 1 radio on browser.the loop some how didt work.

Comment: That is very strange. I've never heard of that happening. Try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the very top of the page and see if any errors are present. This code definitely loops those `<td>` + inputs

Comment: the page is showing like this                                                                            $vals) { // If not the submit button if(is_array($vals)) { // Loop through POST arrays foreach($vals as $sub => $values) // Assign sessions $_SESSION[$letter][$sub] = Plusifier($values,(isset($_SESSION[$letter][$sub]))? $_SESSION[$letter][$sub]:0); } } } ?>
question1  TOTAL:
question2  TOTAL:
question3  TOTAL:
question4  TOTAL:
question5  TOTAL:

Comment: That's all that is showing?? Is your page extension `.php`? Dumb question, I know, but I am trying to think why it would come up like that.

Comment: oh fixed thank you ~~ appreciate your help !! you are the best

Comment: No problem. I thought something screwy was going on there!! I guess if your page isn't a `php` page it makes it hard to run a `php` script!  :D Cheers.